# What is this language construct in JS?

Tags: javascript

Could you please help me to understand what is this in Javascript? What is **a**, what is **a['b']**? How to access the declared content of a construct in the iframe and in the parent window?

```
var a = window['parent'];
if(a) {
    if(a['b']){
        a['b']({
            "c": 1,
            "d": {
                "e": "f",
                "g": false,
                "h": 1
            },
            "i": 0,
            "j": true
        });
    }
}
```

If it is possible give me please a link where I can read about this construction.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [JavaScipt Object Notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Comment: A good place to start would be: ... any JavaScript tutorial, book, introduction or guide.

Comment: Just google "javascript for beginners" and read few resources thoroughly, and do not forget to practice

Comment: I would NOT recommend to start learning JavaScript by such examples! Please pick any JS tutorial with **simple** examples, and when you have mastered all the basic constructs (function calls, JSONs, etc), you can go on with the examples like this one. Or are you trying to read obfuscated code? :)

Comment: Where did you get that code? It's looking for a function called 'b' on the iframe's parent, and calling it.

Comment: @TypeIA, I didn't find this construction anywhere but it works.

Comment: @Nurbol Alpysbayev, this is not for beginners because I didn't find it there.

Comment: @Alex Shesterov, I don't try to learn Javascript. I simply don't know what is that and I can't find this construction anywhere.

Comment: @david, Simple window.b = function(){};? So, for example, how to alert the value of "e" in the iframe and in the parent?

Comment: @meowgoesthedog, no, this is not a JSON construction.

Comment: @williamzo I voted for your question because of the way you defended and reasoned it, and see my answer

Comment: @NurbolAlpysbayev, Thank you very much!

Comment: This code is not one specific "construct" but a mixture of many constructs, one of them being object notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, anyway there are no good questions out there, and it seems you are really care to figure it out, so I'll answer:

```
var a = window['parent']; // here we access the "parent" property of window. Could as well be accessed as "window.parent" (same results)
if(a) { // here we check if "a" is truthy [1]
    if(a['b']){ // here we assume that "a" is an object [2] (associative array in some languages), because we are accessing its "b" property. Also we are checking if the "b" property is truthy. 
        a['b']({ // here we assume that a['b'] is a function, because  parentheses are used. We then pass an object (denoted by curly braces) as an argument.
            "c": 1, // this is object's property (as well as others below)
            "d": { // the nested (child) object begins
                "e": "f",
                "g": false,
                "h": 1
            },
            "i": 0,
            "j": true
        });
    }
}
```

[1] truthy - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

[2] objects - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

P.S. In general it is a bad code. You should never try to write code this way. Things could go wrong, e.g. a['b'] could appear as not a function but some other truthy type. Also this whole thing is obviously unreadable.

Comment: thank you very much for you reply. Maybe I'll figure it out by myself but could you please declare the a['b'] in the parent window in a proper way and please write how to access the declared content of a construct in the iframe and in the parent window? I will try to do this myself without your second reply but with this first reply. Then I will compare the result with yours.

Comment: You cannot access data in/from an iframe. Also I cannot understand your english very well, but I know russkiy :-) (but rules of Stackoverflow prohibits other languages, VRODE)

Comment: Looks like you don't know how to declare this construct and how to use it after initialization. But thanks anyway.